# How to read .SPE images in python

Tags: python

I am creating a python program that requires reading .SPE files of some Xray imaging. However I can't find a proper way to load them and plot them. I have found some stuff on google but I think it just loads and converts spectra to txt, not images.

I hope someone here has experience with that. Here is an image example: https://file.io/J7kyjEekq0zb

Comment: How about sharing an SPE image?

Comment: there you go https://file.io/J7kyjEekq0zb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to open the SPE image you supplied using `imageio`:

```
import imageio.v2 as imageio

im = imageio.imread('tir044.SPE')

print(im.shape)    # prints (1024,1024)
print(im.dtype)    # prints uint16
```

As `im` is a Numpy array, you can now process it with **OpenCV**, `scikit-image`, `wand` or **PIL/Pillow**.